# Aggregation at dimension's category

Tags: powerbi

I have sales fact table.

Product dimension table.

Both are connected using product_id (1:m) relation from dimension to fact table.

The sales table has got salesid, productid, salesamt

Product table has got Productid, productname, product_category. Product name is unique but category is not unique in this table. 1 Product belongs to only 1 category.

I want to create a visual showing avg sales amt by product_category. I have added product_category to table visual. Then added sales amt with aggregation type as avg. Is this right way to do avg in power bi.

My concern is that the connection to the fact table is on product_id so I have seen example where aggregations are performed by product name. But is it ok to perform the aggregations by product category (since this field is not unique unlike product name) or do I need to change my model and have a separate product category table with the product_category_id maybe in sales fact table or product dimension table?

Comment: Aggregating by product_category is fine if the product_category is unique in your system. Mean there no two categories have same name. If two categories can have same name then you need to use product_category_id.

Comment: What do you mean by 2 categories have same name? On what basis do I decide whether to split the dimension table or not to?

Comment: ask yourself when you say this is category 'abc' do you have any doubt which category it is? if not then you have unique category in the system and you no need to refer the id.